# CrmService.Update method does not work for certain attribute

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-4

This is my problem:
all I want to do is update a "contact" entity in Crm 4 using the webservice.

This is my code:

```
CrmService eatupCrmService = CrmInteraction.InitializeCrmService();
contact updatedDelegate = new contact();
CeatupCrmService.Key contactPrimaryKey = new CeatupCrmService.Key();
contactPrimaryKey.Value = delegateId;
updatedDelegate.contactid = contactPrimaryKey;
updatedDelegate.address2_postalcode = delegateDetails.ContactDetailsPhysicalAddressCode;
eatupCrmService.Update(updatedDelegate);
```

I use the `InitializeCrmService()` to also retrieve and it works.
When updating the `address2_postalcode` attribute, I get the following error:

> "Server was unable to process request."

with the exception Detail\InnerText :

> "0x80040216 An unexpected error occurred. Platform".

If I change the code to update another attribute, say I try to update the `mobilephone` attribute
instead of `address2_postalcode` it works without any exceptions thrown.

As soon as I try to update `address2_postalcode` then I get that error. The `address2_postalcode` data type in Crm is `nvarchar`, and the value it is being assigned (`delegateDetails.ContactDetailsPhysicalAddressCode`) is of c#'s `string` type.

Anyone have any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts at trying to understand why this error was occurring, I finally succeeded.

When I started working on this project, the client instructed me to test using only a specific contact, because we were working directly on the production environment. (the client does not have a development environment yet)

After doing some database queries to compare this contact to others (updates were failing only for the test contact) I noticed that my contact's `address2_addressid` attribute was NULL.

I then went to CRM under *Customization\Customize* Entities and opened up the contact entity. Under attributes, I ordered by type and saw that the contact has 3 `primarykey` attributes: `contactid`, `address1_addressid` and `address2_addressid`.

The test contact's `address1_addressid` and `address2_addressid` fields were NULL and this caused the CRM web service to throw the **0x80040216 An unexpected error occurred. Platform** error upon me trying to update any of the address fields.

I don't know why this contact had those IDs set to NULL, I asked and the person that created the contact had no explanation of how this could have happened. I guess this will remain a mystery, but at least I now have an answer to the error I was getting and I can cater for this in my code.

Answer (score 2):

This same error and situation happened to me because I did an SSIS dts to load contacts in CRM from a flat file, in unsopported way, and I forgot to fill the CustomerAddressBase table. After filling this table "correctly" (two rows for each contact) the attributes of the View CustomerAddress(address1_addressid and address2_addressid) became not null. If you don't know how to fill this table (CustomerAddressBase) just create one new contact directly with address fields filled in CRM and then go to SQL Server management studio and by query you can see and know how the fields are filled.

Hope it helps somebody,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know ho it can work...
I think you have to do CrmService.Create(contact) and then with the returned Guid you can perform updates...

Update is not going to work since the record with the Id you are setting on your contact entity doesn´t exist in the db...

```
contact updatedDelegate = new contact();
```

CeatupCrmService.Key contactPrimaryKey = new CeatupCrmService.Key();

You could do something like:

```
crmService eatupCrmService = CrmInteraction.InitializeCrmService();
        contact updatedDelegate = new contact();
        updatedDelegate.address2_postalcode = delegateDetails.ContactDetailsPhysicalAddressCode;
        Guid cId = eatupCrmService.Create(updatedDelegate);
        updatedDelegate.contactid = new Key(cId);
        //set more fields if you want
        eatupCrmService.Update(updatedDelegate);//update record
```

Wish I have helped you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried to get the contact entity before updating its "address2_postalcode" property and i get the same error unfortunately. I did a RetrieveMultiple request to get the contact (as a dynamic entity) and it didn't work either.

Comment: Well... you can try starting SQL Profiler to see exactly what is happening when you do the operation. I can´t think of anything else...

Comment: I ran SQL Profiler and couldn't find the field (address2_postalcode) in the update SQL statement. If i try to udpate the "mobilephone" attribute then i can see it in profiler. Maybe it's some sort of serialization issue with the Crm web service, i don't know... Was trying different workarounds last night till 23:00 and still couldn't get it right. I'm thinking of maybe using the old webservice ("http://crmserver/mscrmservices/2006/CrmServiceWsdl.aspx") and try update it the old way :(

Comment: Like i mentioned before, i'm already retrieving the contact entity so the contactid was correctly assigned. It's the address1_addressid and address2_addressid IDs that were NULL and this is what was causing the update to fail. All other existing contacts have those GUIDs set.